# Upload image from Android to MySQL database

Tags: php, android, json

PHP code

Is anything is wrong in this php code?

```
 <?php
    require '../db_connect.php';
    if (isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message']) or isset($_POST['img_file']) && !empty($_POST['img_file']) or isset($_POST['video_file']) && !empty($_POST['video_file']))
    {
        $message=$_POST['message'];
        $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
        //$user_id=1;
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO posts(user_id,post_description,is_active,created_at) values('".$user_id."','".$message."',1,'".$date."')");

        if($query){
             $i_post_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
             if(isset($_POST['img_file'])){
                 $sourcePath = $_POST['img_file'];
                 // create dir if not exists
                if(!is_dir('../img/Post')){
                     mkdir('../img/Post',0777,true);
                }
                $s_file_name = time()."_".$_POST['img_file'];
                $targetPath = "../img/Post/".$s_file_name;
                if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
                    function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {
                        $info = getimagesize($source);
                        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
                            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
                            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
                            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

                        imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);
                        return $destination;
                    }
                    $source_img = $targetPath;

                    if(!is_dir('../img/Post/compress')){
                        mkdir('../img/Post/compress');
                    }
                    $destination_img = '../img/Post/compress/'.$s_file_name;

                    $d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 50);

                    $i_file_type = 1; // 1 for image.
                    $query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO post_files(post_id,file_name,file_type,is_active) values('".$i_post_id."','".$s_file_name."',$i_file_type,1)");

                }
            }
            if(isset($_POST['video_file'])){
                    //echo "in";
                $sourcePath = $_POST['video_file'];
                 // create dir if not exists
                if(!is_dir('../img/Post')){
                     mkdir('../img/Post',0777,true);
                }

                $s_file_name = time()."_".pathinfo($_POST['video_file'], PATHINFO_FILENAME).".mp4";
                $s_file_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $s_file_name);
                $targetPath = "../img/Post/convert/".$s_file_name; 
                 if(!is_dir('../img/Post/convert')){
                     mkdir('../img/Post/convert',0777,true);
                 }
                $s_post_path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';

                 $handbrake = "HandBrake/HandBrakeCLI";
                 $cmd = $s_post_path.$handbrake." -i ".$sourcePath." -o ".$s_post_path.$targetPath." -e x264 -q 25 -r 15 -B 64 -X 480 -O";
                    passthru($cmd,$err);

                        $i_file_type = 2; // 2 for video.
                        $query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO post_files(post_id,file_name,file_type,is_active) values('".$i_post_id."','".$s_file_name."',$i_file_type,1)");
            }
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Post successfully added.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else{
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

When I am uploading image to Mysql Database its not uploading and showing me image as a string in LOG for example =

```
    img_file = /9j/
4 AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD / 2 wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERATGCgaGBYWGDEjJR0oOjM9PDkz
ODdASFxOQERXRTc4UG1RV19iZ2hnPk1xeXBkeFxlZ2P / 2 wBDARESEhgVGC8aGi9jQjhCY2NjY2Nj
Y2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2P / wAARCBBACSQDASIA
AhEBAxEB / 8 QAGwABAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQACBwYFBAP / xABKEAACAgIBAwMDAQUEBgkDAAsA
AREhMUECA1FhBAVxBhKBkQc1cqGxEyIyNBQVFjNCUiM2U1RVYnOSwRclgiTR4fBDRPFjRSaD / 8 QA
FgEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEC / 8 QAFxEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAERQf / aAAwDAQACEQMR
AD8A8KSAQ2SJQwl4kKkIDoBRP + YJzsANESJ6AGwFuydBEoUypJFoAGPIOhTJhGS4uHOSFAUkxaoy
FQpUSyKj5AGoImKrIQNUCN8nWDAUr5KARqHEgDKARtpAZRpA4yimwEzAvlsJAYrJkQgK0UmbEI0n
CJw1INMgozZaGQCFDNGfgtWBCncfzDRQ9AacSD8otWEgX4FKVbKu5UBlijX2zaKKkDM + BmhwZeAA
skiQCObQRQzoCkHdiAEi2SkvufgCFcmgIBaWUBFYQ9yXYCASqSTL5CjANi2AQosgkIAQGkpCpRcg
LUEkArFghgoAk7RN33JgBrko2ZGXEGQJGo2AzLloAYCiYBJFBAOhULILGS1kCIcAgADTUujIChXk
BAmSZABrjyFxEyYNPAU / kzspKQifJom0ElMWBJjYNtsUBFBovIA + weB2DcvADgDWUDQAUeSspryB
CoMjkCblisGZIBFKwSbcI0lDsAecByiDTdhyYVg1RQgCEHkiCJCBICFFWNkAtwoyZZCAEUdyAmSR
CAFUGknEmQIVACgLkgNOzLCqSAUpQFAvjAvwWVYGSNYLAAREqAimx5OTIGn4Ak2hmwIGTGmooDIG
l5BqwIoEtAEUQsgicaJQTBIBQyZJhTJNgWwGSGIZOvkDI6AQGKMipIBwv6gKVTIOgIs6IpgCLkoy
VSTsICKCXYCGSQutWBlMQYAbbWjJEBQLkgACIUgJG0jIgDBpp2jSyDlu2BEOF8hoAFXsikBVASNO
I / AOMwOME6GG6SCsyT5N5JloAkiICEkotloDStBkuJAGyVDBPEAQFaKAIiggLQ6gLyKfcCZmLNNz
oGghVZQNogAhkCA0n3Ll3MspYCvktkKCp9gTs0ZAiIFkBstEMaoDItt3BNFbAkL5S8AIFIMtyacN
YAOKHnGpBNwMwFFg0bT8GXC0EGkggZ0UqZAoayREAoi0KAKFudQH9SbQEThLyTa0ZAUOUCJAaqCg
AYE / CK0EspkBvZDqAYCrJ5DBrYBDMs0wdAREh5SqgDIkDAhQCArIEKAJKSYAMIoJEnAAyEoABKoI
CBi8wQAaTiPAIVkCJqi2TwBkjULsQAsSTlgaUACoU5yUFIVMJIgJFEMhXKoCLi7Lk5eSifgnmsBU
sgOBQRkDSiHP4Cu4FaJW4FpQSnIA1BI1oHgB5TCsybMvuAERAQrALIgJl5FpwULYAy8DU5FhQkmK
LJLABlwDNQobMgAoi / AQwAlhhU4wRBhgbcQg1kyapbCMkMEuKeaAqSAXQSFQqUArIE / INWOgkIQG
fwSgAlxBpYKJvIOmAtyoMCQAQwWoAUUIkSyBOICC2LaSgAQMnkgFDA6hBPcCBeSltkwhhFQYKQKB
kELgAiVRJTSHXgpi0oYUrg0ZZr7wfKVEACpikDHj4AmnsE40bcPJnAUtlJmCSCHLLBYwKlhQJRYM
A2MAQQpwS / mAsCV5B5JMgAZLVEBSL7xAbsW00AAacQS7gSS2UXJNggGaMsSYAhwSXkWAFEkhbAzB
M070AAOCSkewA2Vk2QEKYQMWA5BsZYAGgNRTBAUFDH8isAZbbyRC1H5AuPJ8H / doW3y8GUxlhQwZ
Mgh4i4MmsoAgnAgAEJQBEyJqwiLRRRAAqgwKAsilLgJKQNNNIyKbWzLAdlEEsE3IDsg2QUuIBYJ0
Ega8i3IeJG / wAMGTXkmArAEvIgAGnRkB0SjsC8kAsTIqwKN6Ik / yTAhxZmSQRr4DRCpABKmieAB5
BIRgKEg2JNUgIJkmCAdkQugJdyvJCwGXBkpJNSBSTIgidALZMCSmkDQqCoCQzVknASBRRRLNNvko
M0gJoDVgBIiDAFuigVaICyKBD5AUzP5IgFudAWikCIB4gAy4Jg5AZKfJkUAtkoIUlEz8gAQLJYCp
txYoMkgNAWQYVpBEAmLCJw15IJogF1WQJ5kgKWAuNKAAULUMnIQwiIoKLAPkm6gWAAxWCgVEWgqQ
pMEUgNTYNyWygAFdyFu6AnaMi8AAkS8kAsCGgA1GgwCewrSdWDZNzoEArk0mpyFkKCBokLwTdJAG
TUwoB0zTwFZGoJPuglhATvA5KAMiTICUZInZLICTTXGZIHgAYoHk0sZAIZCom2TsCcwiwXiS + GAN
sBb7lryBE33KHA4AkTCRykgAkhrQALJqgmR0AEiZSAlQfkQJA4EAJgLVIlGwJUxQEAk2UgBIcgQC
yCCABIkBClRSSAkm3RclDaagnkHLcsAFEhQEgFB5CmfBTNE35AIiiispcgQ / kPucWWgF5hYIEMgQ
zQN2ACApikshWSRomgjKmRipAfAAs2RNEFIxVAikBSJiryDAKBjoJApEyaCFQnLMvJqgCjyXyMEg
hRS8Fl0DphUzIyUBFT0aa2ZSNKeThNIDLyTGgACTsX8FHYBTcFsEKkKn8Asi8gEIOUxIAsq0KgPw
BEKWCiwBJCkiqRkAcaMyPJVJkDUjAJFV2ESYtrSAkBZLXYSfaaAOLgXEVkyyQEJQWAq0PFNgaxnI
BNk8lbJ58hQxRbNPsAPwGUWCTAiyUtsUED41MhRppO0ZdASJsk4B2BGktmUaAp8BEGl9u0DbdaAo
KCHAUEXmS0EGxUgh0BNvZlmn2MtMCGQFAOQFOgbkCWShgL7APFwxbnCgEqEAXFsDUqDLyEScMZM5
YhTOgKgAVbF + BTLDoAgkTZSFLMti / ARYQCsAKbAmA7sgJoVGTMjLAW5eARXHyCA1uiRTRbkAIQYF
YvApSgi4ACGpoICIoCxlgQC5my / qBETICFAmMhRyJKxommAYZpGUIE / ATGhyxgAmAQsFkCYGqDAD
xgnBVHkFPYBhAQqGAbBjNgBKNjSDRBDJAhCoZonEUACsTstAqodAGinwLoAJoBaKAKCIAEmRZoAA
WqKAK0RMghSlgScCgJEhcFWAoZMnkywjUyUWCY5ArJOGOjLAW13AUTYAMSgNVoKIsvA5ABThRCAH
kUgFPuZZoG0wgQoNClsCdkQ0AQQuOwbAlkX3ApAnZPwTZIKGKkhSoDLkjW7KFKuQBAhcLY8YAo2B
pwWQrOEBpwidOAjIoDVBFLagJgUEBUQpKLBgVCu5mRQQtrtYPA0tFlBWTWggVkBSA1xmycRIGSLZ
ADjsSFkkFDsoYuOxaCBEOES8gBEX5AtizJqaAHgeOCDACy0TckgLwSYMFmgNyk7CtAxXkBRcv5Ah
8 ADUAabSV2zACUkQERIpANihSB5AkKhqEZIBmGUgXwAwyFRcgwKWnKFOVEmRAiUkQFgpJpxNA + wC
P3OIMo1AAUrsTKJAiRGkpU0BnZMSfeALKMiieQJMiXcWADAQKAGigWH3SrAiNKIsgAmoFAADGxcR
RKgoafYPBqYB0ESSdFyqiAKkJImAMkPGHknE0EBQQptAUEyVuxdVMgZIWQFBFMA2A0UgQFIyCICG
aAkFTEvgpqAJWLhpGZKwEieClATgCIIkKsIEAotWQgUptE92Tj4BOwNKkDKYVBIE
```

How can I upload an image from this php file? What is wrong in this php file?

Comment: As i think the problem is with  **$s_file_name** You're setting `$s_file_name = $_POST` which returns itself an array of $_files What you need to do is `$s_file_name=$_FILES['img_file']['name']`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend converting image to **Base64** **string** before sending and then **converting it back to image** at back-end using **PHP** code. You can use following code to convert image into **Base64**:

```
public void toStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Send `encodedImage` string to your PHP web-services using your preferred library (I generally use Volley).

Once you received `encodedImage`, use following code to **convert it back to image** and store it at any **location** on your database:

```
$imageString = $_POST['encodedImage'];
$path = "../$name.jpg";
file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($imageString));
```

Once stored, insert **location of the image** in your **MySQL** database so that you can use it to retrieve image.

**Edit:**

Instead of making image upload so complicated, try following PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['img_file'])){
    $sourcePath = $_POST['img_file'];
    // create dir if not exists
    if(!is_dir('../img/Post')){
         mkdir('../img/Post',0777,true);
    }
    $date = date_create();
    $s_file_name = $user_id.date_format($date, 'U');
    $targetPath = "../img/Post/$name.jpg";
    file_put_contents($targetPath, base64_decode($sourcePath));
    $i_file_type = 1; // 1 for image.
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO post_files(post_id,file_name,file_type,is_active) values('".$i_post_id."','".$s_file_name."',$i_file_type,1)");
}
```

---

Check the same code at my GitHub repo: [ImagetoString](https://github.com/harshildarji/CharotarExplore/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/harshil/charotarexplore/home.java#L338-L344)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your PHP file, it works for me:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "image_db";

$db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

if ($db) {
  echo "connected";
}
else{
  echo "not connected";
}

    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['img_name']);

    $target = "images/".basename($image);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images_tbl (image, img_name) VALUES ('$image', '$image_text')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
      echo $msg;
    }else{
        $msg = "Failed to upload image";
      echo $msg;
    }

  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images_tbl");
?>
```